# Laravel polymorphic relation with user_id

Tags: laravel

I have a bookmark system. Where user can bookmark a forum & feed.

I am trying to use a polymorphic relationship. But I can't figure out how to use user_id with polymorphic relations. I want to use eloquent to fetch all feed bookmarks & forum bookmarks separately for a user. I am confused about what relationship to use where!

Business rules I want to achieve -

1. **User** can **Bookmark** Many **Feed** & **Forum**
2. **Feed** & **Forum** can be **Bookmark** by **User**

```
//Users table 

id ----- name ----- email ----- password
```

```
//Feeds table 

id ----- title ----- description
```

```
//Forums table 

id ----- title ----- description
```

```
//Bookmarks table 

id ----- user_id ----- bookmarkable_id ----- bookmarkable_type
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function bookmarks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Bookmark');
    }
}
```

**Bookmark model**

```
class Bookmark extends Model
{
    public function bookmarkable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Feed model**

```
class Feed extends Model
{
    public function bookmarked_by(){
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\User', 'bookmarkable');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also not sure how to do this!

Comment: Add the fields of the models to better understand what you have. 

An easier way of approaching this would be to use the `Many to Many` relationship in Eloquent, where the bookmarks table acts as the pivot table.

Comment: Seems that your `$this->morphToMany('App\Models\User', 'bookmarkable');` on `Feed` is wrong, try to change the `'App\Models\User'` to `'App\Models\Bookmark'`

Comment: I have added a few fields of all models